# Mod Rewrite not redirecting as expected

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have rewrite rule to redirect to www and rewrite rules to redirect to ssl. This is my desired setup and everything works perfectly except when I add this new condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new-review?.* [NC]
```

If that condition is true I do not want the ssl redirect to happen. The problem I am seeing is that when I do this the entire url redirects to https://www.example.com/index.php?query=string

The normal behavior even for every other page works just fine. the URI stays the same but index.php is run. Here is my htaccess file below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new-review?.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

My expected behavior is someone types in the url http://www.example.com/new-review?query=string and this page runs the code on index.php without switching the users uri to index.php. I just can't figure out why the last rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule . index.php
```

follows expected behavior for everything except that one condition. All I want is for this one page to work as a non-ssl page but still run via index.php.

Comment: First of all, you are rewriting the non-www version to HTTPS already – in that case your RewriteCond for /new-review comes too late already. And a RewriteCond only affects the RewriteRule that follows it, so your last rule is not dependent on the condition checking for `!^/new-review?.*`  in your current setup.

Comment: But assuming the url they enter at is "http:// www example.com/new-review?query=string" then the first condition would fail and nothing would happen, the second condition should fail and nothing would happen and the third condition should always happen as long as the file or directory new-review does not exist. It seems like the last RewriteRule to index.php is sending an external redirect instead of just internally rewriting the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important trick is to use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI` in your condition. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and **it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules**.

So you can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^\s/new-review [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Accepting this as the answer because it is simple and doesn't require too much change to current code. Giving a +1 to the answer by jon because he explains a little better why this was happening. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite engine will loop until the URI stops changing. What happens when you request `/new-review` is it doesn't match any of the redirect rules, then it matches the last rule and it gets applied, thus `/new-review` is rewritten to `/index.php`. Now, the rewrite engine loops, and the new URI is applied. This time, your second rule matches the URI (`/index.php`) and thus gets redirected. If you don't want index.php to get redirected, then you need to either prevent all looping, or add a passthrough:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new-review?.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

or

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new-review?.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Excellent explanation of why this was happening. I guess I didn't fully understand the process this follows. You answer was extremely helpful for me going forward. +1